# Google-drive-java-api-returns-deleted-files

Tags: google-drive-api

I have tried to get push notification for when i am editing that drive files.
Everything was fine until I tried to delete these folders from Google Drive UI. They disappeared from the UI, but my service still receives them as if they were present.

```
 try {
        configdata = dao.getConfigByChannelId(channelId,IntegrationType.DRIVE);
        System.out.println("ACCESS TOKEN FOR CHANNEL ID: " + configdata.getAccessToken());
        GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential().setAccessToken(configdata.getAccessToken());

        Drive service = new Drive.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, null)
                .setApplicationName("Akoonu")
                .setHttpRequestInitializer(credential).build();
        Files.List files = service.files().list();

        try { 
            Change change = service.changes().get(String.valueOf((Integer.parseInt(changeId) - 1))).execute();


            System.out.println("Changed file ID: " + change.getFileId());
            System.out.println("Check delete case: " + change.getDeleted());


            if (change.getDeleted()) {
                System.out.println("File has been deleted");
                File changedFile = change.getFile();

                strpath.replace(changedFile.getTitle(), "");
                String path = strpath.replace(changedFile.getTitle(), "");
                //deleteItem = iao.getIventoryItemByFilePathAndConfigId(changedFile.getTitle(), path, configdata.getId(), configdata.getAccountId());
                deleteItem = iao.getIventoryItemByExternalId(changedFile.getId(), configdata.getId(), configdata.getAccountId());
                itemService.deleteInventoryItem(deleteItem.getId(), deleteItem.getAccountId());
                //deleteFilePathList.add(metadata.getPathDisplay().substring(1));

            } else {
                File changedFile = change.getFile();
                System.out.println("Changed file Title: " + changedFile.getTitle());


          .
          .
          .
          .
          .
```

I have tried lot of samples but still not fixed.Plz help me.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I am also facing this type of issues on my project but after a long time i got a solution .

Please use query String parameter in your code like

```
Files.List request = service.files().list().setQ("trashed=false");
 ..
```

Surely it will fix that issue.

THanks.

Answer (score 0):

In v3 there's  a "explicitlyTrashed" trashed flag, and that was what solved it for me (for now)

https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files